# Accessing instance constructor argument within a method

Tags: python

Just a quick question, so i have a class named `animal` and when you create the class you can initialise it with a `dogName`.

```
class animal:

    def __init__(self, dogName):
        self._owner = ""
        self._address = ""

    def setOwnerDetails(self, name, address):
        self._owner = name
        self._address = address

    def getDetails(self):
        return self._owner, self._address

    def getName(self):
        return self.dogName
        ##Does not work, trying to access constructor argument.
```

So when you initialise the instance with a value, which is dogName and in this instance the Dogname is Lucy, how can i access this value within a method?
I know i can do this by creating a instance variable but is there any other way i can do it. The variable above understandable does not work but is there any other way?

```
dog1 = animal("Lucy")
dog1.setOwnerDetails("Thomas", "35 Trop")
result = dog1.getDetails()
print(dog1.getName())  # trying to print the dog Name that is in the constructor argument.
```

Any help will be appreciated, I might not have explained it well.

Comment: No, you have to explicitly bind the argument value to an instance (or class) attribute to access it in other methods. Why don't you just do `self.dog_name = dog_name` (note PEP8-compliant naming)?

Comment: As an aside, you should probably use `set_owner_details` inside `__init__`, rather than duplicate the assignments to `self._owner` and `self._address`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dog_name` as an instance attribute in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, dog_name):
    self._owner = ""
    self._address = ""
    self.dog_name = dog_name
```

You will then be able to access the attribute in the methods using `self.dog_name`.

**Aside**: as @jonrsharpe mentions in the comments, you should change your variable name from `dogName` to `dog_name` for PEP-8 compliance.

Comment: if you start with PEP-8: Class names should start with capital letters

Comment: Yes - there are several PEP-8 (and general) improvements which could be made to the code, but I've chosen to mainly just focus on solving the user's specific question without confusing them with too much detail!